# Keyboard handling in a winforms app

Tags: winforms, events, keyboard, focus

I'm building a WinForms app which looks roughly like this:

[image]

There is a single Form, with a menu, toolbar, status bar, a navigation tree, a custom drawing canvas (which is a UserControl that accepts keyboard input and draws text and also renders a caret) and a Find panel which allows the user to search for text.

I'm having difficulty with getting these behaviors to work:

1) The accelerators on the Find Panel (e.g. 'c' for Match case and 'w' for Whole words) prevent those characters from being entered into the canvas, even when the canvas has focus.

2) Pressing ESC when the focus is anywhere but the canvas should return the focus to the canvas. In particular, this should work when the Find textbox has focus. Can this be done by hooking the keyboard at a single point rather than for each possible focused control?

Answer (score 2):

In the case where you have multiple controls competing for the keyboard input, set the Forms [`KeyPreview Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) to `True` in order to handle your KeyPress events in the Form's KeyPress event handler. You can then direct the keyboard input accordingly.

From above MSDN link:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus.

---

See if something like this works for you, it still will allow you to do a simultaneous <kbd>Alt</kbd> + Accelerator Key but will set the focus back to the usercontrol if it had focus and the <kbd>Alt</kbd> was pressed:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ActiveControl.Name == userControl11.Name )
        {
            if (e.Alt)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                userControl11.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - that may work for question #2. Any ideas about the first question?

Comment: @bright I have used the same procedure for both. Just look for the respective modifier keys.

Comment: I see - unfortunately this means checking each modifier explicitly. Will do this if there's no general approach, but am still holding out for one.

Comment: @bright I finally got a chance to sit down at my computer. In testing out situation, using a TextBox instead of your Custom UserControl pressing the <alt> will prevent the initial press of any of the assigned accelerator's from being sent to the TextBox, any subsequent ones are, until the <alt> is pressed again.

Comment: With a UserControl, the assigned accelerators always cause the Find Panel to gain focus, and the keypresses never get routed to the UserControl. As another example, assume KeyPreview is set to true on the Form. Now, if 'c' is pressed while renaming an item in the tree, the Form will receive the keypress. How should the code in the form proceed? In this case, the tree has focus and should receive the keypress. But how can this logic be generalized?